# Keyhole routing 'endgrain' of plywood

Tags: plywood, router, router-bit

I have seen [this article](https://www.woodmagazine.com/woodworking-tips/techniques/routing/keyholes-bits) about using a keyhole router cutter in order to hang shelves, cutting into the edge of the board rather than the face.

[image]

I know that this should be fine for the solid wood being used in the article, but I'm wondering if this would be viable for plywood also?

In my use case, I am thinking of using a keyhole slot to stop a bookcase from moving and coming away from the wall rather than it supporting any vertical weight.

Would the plys be up to the stress of a lateral force? Again, its not like somebody will be climbing on this bookcase or pulling at it in any way.

Comment: No you'd want to keyhole plates for plywood.

Comment: That was my other thought. Guess I'd have to hog out the space for the screw to fit in and then a recess for the plate itself.

Comment: Yes, generally you cut or mill out a very shallow mortise for the plate (which are often rectangular but not always) and under that you need a deeper recess. Generally the easiest way to create the deeper recess is by drilling; if you route out the mortise it might seem obvious to use the router for that operation as well, but you'd have to see how the plies of your plywood respond to the router bit.

Comment: _"...its not like somebody will be climbing on this bookcase or pulling at it in any way..."_ Until one day somebody does.... The plywood will handle a lot of force, but the keyhole brackets (if that's how you decide to do it) may not if they are not fastened well.